# Autofac register type with constructor

Tags: c#, autofac, asp.net-core-2.0

I have class:

```
public class FunctionExtender : IFunctionsExtender
{
  private static IOptions<Settings> _settings;       
  private static ILogger<FunctionExtender> _logger;

  public FunctionExtender(IOptions<Settings> settings, ILogger<FunctionExtender> logger)
  {
    _settings = settings;
    _logger = logger;
  }
}
```

where `IOptions` is a `Microsoft.Extensions.Options` type and `ILogger` is a `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` type. How can I register this type in Autofac container with it parameters? I tried something like that:

```
var container = new ContainerBuilder();
container.Populate(services);
container.RegisterType<FunctionExtender>()
                .WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(IOptions<Settings>), ???));
```

but I don't know what to pass as second argument.

Comment: You should refrain from letting your application components depend on `IOptions<T>` as explained [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html#working-with-ioption-t).

Comment: Also, prevent injecting `ILogger<T>` and prefer injecting the much simpler `ILogger` into your components. You can wire this up with an Autofac.Module as shown [here](https://github.com/nblumhardt/autofac-serilog-integration/blob/dev/src/AutofacSerilogIntegration/ContextualLoggingModule.cs) for Serilog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to register `FunctionExtender` as `IFunctionsExtender`. Autofac will resolve the appropriate dependencies for you. It is one of the jobs of an inversion of control (IoC) container - register, resolve, release and dispose.

As of `Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection Version 4.2.0`, here is all you need for `ASP.Net Core 2`.

```
public class Startup
{
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
      ...
      services.AddMvc();
      ...
   }

   public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
   {
      builder.RegisterType<FunctionExtender>().As<IFunctionsExtender>();
   }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddAutofac()) <======
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```